# Sencha extjs4.0 : can't load the GmapPanel

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.window.*',
    'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
        myMask.show();

        var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            //renderTo: 'layout',
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            //title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                title: 'Message List',
                region: 'south',     // position for region
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 100,
                split: true,         // enable resizing
                collapsible: true,
                margins: '0 5 5 5',
                collapsed: true
            },{
                //title: 'Map',
                region: 'center',    
                xtype: 'gmappanel',
                center: {geoCodeAddr: '4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA, 02215-3409, USA',marker: {title: 'Fenway Park'}}
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
        }); 
        myMask.hide();
});
```

### Question

1. Why can't load the gmappanel?
2. I'm trying to show the Loading Mask, when Page complete loaded only remove the loading mask? how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
                xtype: 'gmappanel',
                id : 'mygooglemap',
                mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
                mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],   
                zoomLevel: 2,
                gmapType: 'map',
                center: {geoCodeAddr: 'Malaysia'}
```

Try This code workable for u or not.